# Doctrine classloader overwrites my __autoload function

Tags: php, doctrine, classloader, autoload

I may generally misunderstand something about setting up a custom classloader.

What happens is that once i initialize it:

```
use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader;

require_once(DOCTRINE_PATH . '/Common/ClassLoader.php');
classLoader=new ClassLoader('Doctrine', DOCTRINE_PATH);
classLoader->register();
```

My previously defined function

```
function __autoload(){}
```

No longer works.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After diving a bit deeper into the autoload documentation, i found that in order to have multiple autoloaders at the same time, the use of

```
function __autoload(){}
```

is not a valid route to take. Instead, one has to define a custom autoload function, such as

```
function MyAutoLoader()
```

and then use

```
spl_autoload_register('MyAutoLoader');
```

to register it onto the autoload stack.

Finally, using this method, my autoloader is no longer overwritten by implementing the Doctrine classloader.